# CSS styles not displaying in angularjs text field

Tags: javascript, php, css, angularjs

I have this code below and I want to style it with CSS but my stylesheet only affects the titles and not the text in the boxes when clicked. How can I make my CSS stylesheet effective on the text? Or how can I target that text to style it?

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'Styles displayed here', info: {text: 'Styles not displayed here', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
      {name: 'obj3', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj3', show: false}},
      {name: 'obj4', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj4', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          <pre>{{ x.info.text }}</pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem because tr.info has the style.
What is exactly your problem ?

Comment: @ArnaudGueras The text field does not display styles from my CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Do you mean your bootstrap table styles? Also, please note that you have an unclosed "<td> {{ x.name }}".

Comment: @user1582024 I want to style {{ x.info.text }}

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Bootstrap to see what a correctly styled text would look like in that context, but you can just add a "class" attribute to that <pre> to style it. Also, do you mean the monospace font? That's because the <pre> element designates pre-formatted text, like computer code. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: @user1582024 I have solved the problem (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was using two stylesheets in one page which were conflicting each other, so removing one solved the problem.